# why is my html dialog in react not rendering above my content?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to render an HTML dialog element in ReactJs. I was under the impression that it would render on top of my content. In my use case I have a gallery of photos and when a user clicks a photo I want a Modal to pop up.

```
import './Project.css'
export default function Project({title, thumbnail_url, images, id}){
    function toggleModal(id){
        const modal = document.getElementById(id);
        const isOpen = modal?.open;
        if (isOpen){
            modal.close()
        }
        else modal.showModal()
    }
    return(
        <>
        <div className="project" onClick={()=>toggleModal(id)}>
            <h2 className='headline project-title'>{title}</h2>
            <img src={thumbnail_url} alt="" />
            <dialog className='modal' id={id} >
            <div>Dialoge</div>
            <button onClick={()=>toggleModal(id)}>close</button>
            </dialog>
        </div>
        
    </>
```

I expected the dialog element to render above my photo gallery like a modal yet it renders below the rest of the page content. Do I need to use a ReactJa portal for an HTML dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the ReactJs isn't VanillaJs DOM manipulating. You have to use `useState` and change the `state` to toggle. Because the first load has happened once in the VDOM and then ReactDOM did colligate the VDOM to the main DOM.

Now for any change, some re-rendering should be happened. And here it will be possible by using `useState`.

Another thing, for choosing an element in the VDOM/DOM it was highly recommended to use `useRef`.

```js
import './Project.css';
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Project({title, thumbnail_url, images, id}){
    const [isOpen, setOpenClose] = useState(false);
    const dialogRef = useRef();

    function toggleModal(){
        if (isOpen){
            setOpenClose(false);
            dialogRef.current?.close();
        }
        else {
            setOpenClose(true);
            dialogRef.current?.showModal();
        }
    }
    return(
        <>
        <div className="project" onClick={()=>toggleModal(id)}>
            <h2 className='headline project-title'>{title}</h2>
            <img src={thumbnail_url} alt="" />
            <dialog className="modal" ref={dialogRef} >
              <div>Dialoge</div>
              <button onClick={()=>toggleModal(id)}>close</button>
            </dialog>
        </div>
        
    </>
```

Comment: So i tried that out and was still having the same issue, then I created a codesanbox with your code and the issue was gone. After some tweaking I found the source of the issue. I was using  the new css reset library  which had these lines in it *:where(:not(iframe,canvas,img,svg,video):not(svg *)) {
    all: unset;
    display: revert;
}
This was effecting the dialog element. By adding dialog{all:revert} the issue is resolved. How should I mark this solution solved?

Comment: To showing it as solved post, the green check mark is enough, so your problem was another thing, you had got CSS issue. But in ReactJs world use ref instead of DOM selecting. It seems dialog tag doesn't need useState, thanks, I learned new thing, I will edit my answer